# ftruncate() failed for hugepages

Tags: c, linux, centos7, mmap, huge-pages

My application tried to `ftruncate()` and `mmap()`-ed 32-33KB with a 2MB hugepage but it exited.

Then I realized that `ftruncate()` failed:

```
int fd = open("/mnt/huge2m/test", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666);
int rc0 = ftruncate(fd, size);
if (0 != rc0) {
    fprintf(stderr,
        "Can't ftruncate shared memory segment: %d, %lu, errno = %d, err = %s\n",
        fd, size, errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

And it exited:

```
Can't ftruncate shared memory segment: 5, 32896, errno = 22, err = Invalid argument
terminate called without an active exception
```

I checked `/mnt/huge2m` where I mounted my hugepage fs.  I do see the file was created there but with zero size.

Then I checked whether I still have free 2MB hugepages:

```
$ numastat -vm

Per-node system memory usage (in MBs):
                          Node 0          Node 1           Total
                 --------------- --------------- ---------------
MemTotal                96936.38        98304.00       195240.38
MemFree                 94171.20        95491.38       189662.58
MemUsed                  2765.17         2812.62         5577.80
Active                     79.84          416.48          496.32
Inactive                  136.42           57.93          194.35
Active(anon)               22.71            4.80           27.52
Inactive(anon)              9.20            0.01            9.21
Active(file)               57.13          411.68          468.80
Inactive(file)            127.21           57.92          185.14
Unevictable                 0.00            0.00            0.00
Mlocked                     0.00            0.00            0.00
Dirty                       0.00            0.00            0.00
Writeback                   0.00            0.00            0.00
FilePages                 193.86          470.31          664.17
Mapped                     16.09            1.28           17.37
AnonPages                  22.45            4.84           27.29
Shmem                       9.52            0.05            9.56
KernelStack                 7.42            4.59           12.02
PageTables                  2.75            0.32            3.07
NFS_Unstable                0.00            0.00            0.00
Bounce                      0.00            0.00            0.00
WritebackTmp                0.00            0.00            0.00
Slab                       94.56           47.73          142.30
SReclaimable               34.54           19.01           53.55
SUnreclaim                 60.02           28.73           88.75
AnonHugePages               0.00            0.00            0.00
HugePages_Total            80.00           80.00          160.00
HugePages_Free             80.00           12.00           92.00
HugePages_Surp              0.00            0.00            0.00
```

I still have quite a bit (92MB).

Then, I checked the limit as suggested by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304716/mmap-returning-enomem):

```
$ cat /proc/22749/limits 
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes     
Max resident set          unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max processes             4096                 767758               processes 
Max open files            1024                 4096                 files     
Max locked memory         65536                65536                bytes     
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks     
Max pending signals       767758               767758               signals   
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes     
Max nice priority         0                    0                    
Max realtime priority     0                    0                    
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
```

My application only opens like < 10 files.

I also thought that my user opened too many files, reaching its (hard) limit.  Tho, if it were the case, when I attempted to `open()` the file (the hugepage), I should have got -1 instead of 5 (which is a valid fd descriptor and the file wouldn't be created in `/mnt/huge2m`).

`strace` doesn't show much:

```
open("/mnt/huge2m/test", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666) = 5
ftruncate(5, 32896)                    = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(2, "Can't ftruncate shared mem segme"..., 82Can't ftruncate shared mem segment: 5, 262272, errno = 22, err = Invalid argument
) = 82
```

Any idea?

Comment: Linux produces EINVAL also on "file not open for writing"

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt yes, my bad.  let me fix it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I included how I opened the file with read-write access.  It didn't return -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files in the huge pages filing system may only be a integer number huge pages in length, in your case a multiple of 2MB. You should not use huge pages for such a small amount of memory.

Comment: Interesting that regular shared memory pages (usually 4K) is allowed to be `ftruncate()`-ed to whatever size but hugepages aren't allowed.  Thanks!  Just a side question if you don't mind -- do you know how to properly clean up a mmap-ed hugeages (mapped to a mounted hugepage fs)? I still see the files there even I `close()` and `mumap()` it sometimes.  Thanks.